# How to fix "cannot move out of dereference of `std::cell::Ref<'_, servo_url::ServoUrl>`" compile error with closure

Tags: rust

I'm working on a PR for Servo and I'm trying to determine whether or not the request URL shares an origin with a list of URLs provided in a response header. I'm trying to determine this using a closure run inside a fold call on the list of URLs. The closure needs to use the request URL but rustc is complaining that the request URL doesn't have the copy trait.

To resolve this, I tried to clone the URL and then put it in a RefCell, and then borrow it from there but now I'm getting the current error and I have no idea how to resolve it.

```rust
let url = request.current_url();
//res is the response
let cloned_url = RefCell::new(url.clone());
let req_origin_in_timing_allow = res
    .headers()
    .get_all("Timing-Allow-Origin")
    .iter()
    .map(|header_value| {
        ServoUrl::parse(header_value.to_str().unwrap())
            .unwrap()
            .into_url()
    })
    .fold(false, |acc, header_url| {
        acc || header_url.origin() == cloned_url.borrow().into_url().origin()
    });
```

Exact compiler error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `std::cell::Ref<'_, servo_url::ServoUrl>`
    --> components/net/http_loader.rs:1265:70
     |
1265 |         .fold(false, |acc, header_url| acc || header_url.origin() == cloned_url.borrow().into_url().origin());
     |                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `servo_url::ServoUrl`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Based on the naming of `into_url`, I would guess it consumes `self`. I don't really understand why you have introduced a `RefCell`. It seems like you just need to clone the url at that point rather than earlier. ie. `url.clone().into_url().origin()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`into_*()` functions, such as `into_url()` by convention take ownership of `self`, which means they destroy (or recycle) their input, leaving nothing behind.

With `.borrow()` you're only allowed to see the value, but not destroy it.

So either call `.clone()` to obtain your own copy to pass to `into_url()`, or if you can work with borrowed values, try `as_url()` that borrows instead of destroying the original.